# Why does my Swift button show a small blue square when tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created a custom button that is designable in storyboard, and i styled the button select state. Now when i tap the button blue square appear above that. This is my code:

Swift version: 4.0

```
@IBDesignable class CircularButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 255.0, green: 153.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 3.0

    @IBInspectable var bgColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            updateButton()
        }
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpButton()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapp), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setUpButton() {
        self.backgroundColor = self.bgColor
        let  cornerRadius = (self.frame.size.width + self.frame.size.height) / 4
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }

    @objc func btnTapp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isSelected == false {
            isSelected = !isSelected
        } else if isSelected == true {
            isSelected = !isSelected
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            updateState(state: isSelected)
        }
    }

    func updateState(state: Bool) {
        if state == false {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
            print("fls")
        } else if state == true {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
            print("tre")
        }
    }
}
```

these are image of my problem [in selected state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahf4y.png):
[is unselect state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIoPu.png)

Comment: I can't  understand - what i do?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot delete updateButton- this method does not special work.

Comment: If your button's type is "System" in your storyboard, try setting it to "Custom".

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler - so tnx comrade the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TylerTheCompiler wrote:

If your button's type is "System" in your storyboard, try setting it to "Custom".

Then, original poster wrote:

so tnx comrade the problem is solved

(Just marking this as Answered, so it doesn't look unanswered in the future.)